# Make PHP show the files in the folder

Tags: php, list, pdf, post

I'm working on my project. A reading app.

But I want to do something to help with it, I have over 12,000 pdf's to put into the application.

I wanted to put the pdf in the folder it appeared the way it is shown in the picture below

Or the method used there and a post? help me

Obs like this [image: like this]
Sorry for some English error, I'm not fluent yet.

Comment: You've shown nine out of 12,000 PDFs with little indication of what that's supposed to tell us. Please explain better.

Comment: Are getting the data from database.. Or you just want to display all PDF files from particular folder

Comment: Have you tried asking PHP nicely? Also we need a bit more details.

Comment: I would like to put the .pdf file in the folder. And that he would appear on the list. Similar to the photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can try this:

```
<?php
$dir = 'my_pdf_files'; 
foreach (glob($dir . '/*.pdf') AS $fname)
{
   echo '<div class="blue">' . basename($fname) . '</div>';
}
?>

<style>
.blue
{
    background-color: #33383E;
    color: #C7C8C8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #14161A;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Why -1? Please explain whoever downvoted it what's wrong here.

Comment: I can't say for the first downvote, but the tooltip explains "this answer is not useful". I can imagine that one point why it is not useful is, because it duplicates existing Q&A material that is on site already.